# Generating Incremental (or Random without duplicated data) Numbers from a randomly generated number within an Access Calculated Query Field

Tags: ms-access, random, increment

Objective: I need an Access Query to randomly generate 3-digit numbers that are used to create a unique serial number for all serial numbers generated on a specific date. Half of the serial number is generated via the ship date, and therefore the 3-digit value must be completely unique for the set of records returned (could be up to 100 records for a given day).

To generate a random number, I am using the following function:

Int((900-100+1)*Rnd()+100)

This function generates the number randomly between 100 and 900 for the first record returned in the query. The problem is that each record below that 1st record contains the same number, hence creating duplicated serial numbers for each record returned in the query.

What I need is to either implement an increment function that can increase the value of the original randomly generated number by 1, or create syntax that tells Access to randomly generate numbers without the 100-900 range for all records returned without the possibility of a duplicate number assigned.

Thank you SO MUCH in advance for the help!

Erik

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Do you really need the number portion to be "random", or do you just need to ensure that it is "unique" (in that it hasn't already been used for a given ship date). If the latter, and it is okay for them to be sequential, and you are using Access_2010 or later, you could use an event-driven Data Macro for that.

Comment: Make sure you have called `VBA.Randomize` which initialises the randomizer. BS. Why don't you just format your record id to [first half of serial]-[001..002..100]?

Answer (score 0):

You must *seed* Rnd. The traditional method is to Timer for that:

```
=Int((900-100+1)*Rnd(-Timer())+100)
```

To prohibit dupes, have in mind please, that random is random, thus the only method is to check that each generated number hasn't been used before - and if it has, run the function again.

This means, that when you approach the limit, it will take more and more loops to generate an unused number.